# Close modal if a button inside is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to do is single page form switch with the help of modal dialog in bootstrap.

My problem is when i click the button in modal dialog the the modal dialog wont close but the form switch is successfully switched... Does anyone know how to to make the modal dialog close if i clicked any of the button in the modal?

HTML of modal dialog:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Click me</a></li>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
           <form class="form-horizontal">
             <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                 <button type="button" id="show_first" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">First</button>
                 <button type="button" id="show_second" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Second</button>
               </div>
             </div>
           </form>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="myFirst">
    <div class="row">
      <center>
        <h1>First Page</h1>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySecond">
    <div class="row">
      <center>
        <h1>Second Page</h1>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.myFirst').hide();
        $('.mySecond').hide();
        $('#show_first').click(function(){
            $('.mySecond').hide();
            $('.myFirst').show();
            return false;
        });
        $('#show_second').click(function(){
            $('.myFirst').hide();
            $('.mySecond').show();
                return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Title is a bit confusing!

Comment: You can close the modal from the click event bound to your buttons by calling `$('.modal').modal('hide')` on your modal window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, in bootstrap you can call `.modal('hide')` to close your modal window, so you can add it to you bound click events like so:

```
$('#show_first').click(function(){
    $('.mySecond').hide();
    $('.myFirst').show();
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
    return false;
});

$('#show_second').click(function(){
    $('.myFirst').hide();
    $('.mySecond').show();
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
    return false;
});
```